# What is a CLI helper/wrapper that allows a dumb CLI program to have a command history?

Tags: command-line, readline

Many years ago I came across a simple utility that would handle the keyboard interaction for any CLI-based program that did not support command history. This tool would keep track of the commands you issued to the program, and allow you to use up/down arrow keys to go through your command history, and even edit the commands before re-issuing them to your program.

For example, let's say you have a CLI-based program, called 'dumb', which does not support command recall and edits. You would specify this program ('dumb') as an argument to the wrapper program. Let's call the wrapper 'cli-wrapper'. To invoke 'dumb' under this environment, you'd issue the following command..

```
cli-wrapper dumb
```

The wrapper then (I assume) forks and runs dumb as a child, with all keyboard I/O being funneled through cli-wrapper (thus enabling command history and editing) and passed to the dumb application.

I used such a tool many years ago, but I've since forgotten the name of the tool. Searches come up empty. But I'm sure the tool exists. If anyone has a recollection of the name of this program, I'd be appreciative!

Comment: Yes! It is rlwrap! Not sure why I couldn't come up with a search that answered my  question when I did my initial searches (which is why I eventually posted this dupe question)